# Express Js API Http to Https not working

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, amazon-ec2, https

I tried from HTTP to HTTPS for my domain but I getting an error.

I Have written API's using express.js 4 running on port 8081. My front end running on port 80 Nginx. SSL certificate provider is Amazon and I am using load balancer successfully running with https.

I have to run my API using HTTPS, below I am getting error

```
_tls_common.js:85
      c.context.setKey(options.key, options.passphrase);
                ^
Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:85:17)
    at Server (_tls_wrap.js:776:25)
    at new Server (https.js:27:14)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:48:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/ubuntu/server.js:95:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
```

My node js code:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var options = {
   key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem',{passphrase: 'XXXXX'}),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'),

 };

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, app);

httpServer.listen(8081);

httpsServer.listen(8081);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch" means that the private key doesn't match the SSL certificate (x509 certificate)

Answer (score 1):

I just create key and cert file and include as following.

```
var app = require('../app');
var server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/driver_app/key.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/driver_app/cert.crt', 'utf8'),
     requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},app);
```

where app is my express app. This works fine for me

Comment: you are using self-created key. I am using amazon provided ssl certificate private key found in path `/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem`